# how to recall function from controller using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

```
setInterval(makeAjaxCall(),5000);

        function makeAjaxCall() {
            var url = '/Lines/dbcheck/?LineID=@ViewBag.LineID&ProductID=@ViewBag.ProductID&LastID=@LastID';
            var data = {};
            $.get(url, data, function(response_text){
                if (response_text == 1)
                {
                    document.location.reload();
                }
                else
                {
                    setInterval(makeAjaxCall(),5000);
                }
            }, "text");
        }
```

I already can call function from controller but only 1 time. I would like to create function to check the data from database and return 1 or 0. If it is 0 i would like to make a delay for 5 sec and then recall function again.

the problem is the parameter `response_text` is not updated because I can call the function from controller only first time

Comment: Your else block is not needed because it adds a further timer every 5 seconds if response_text != 1. Instead, you should kill your timer exactly *when* response_text *is* 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
setInterval(makeAjaxCall(),5000);

        function makeAjaxCall() {

           $.ajax({      
                cache : false,    
                dataType: "json",      
                type: "GET",
                async:false,
                url: url ,
                success: function (fdata) { 
                if (fdata == 1)
                {
                    document.location.reload();
                }
                else
                {
                    setInterval(makeAjaxCall(),5000);
                }
             },
            error: function (reponse) {                                     
                }
            });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code executed immediately because of you passing `()` it is not wait for the time delay.

```
setInterval(makeAjaxCall(), 5000);
```

change to

```
setInterval(makeAjaxCall, 5000);
```

or alternate way

```
setInterval(function() { 
  makeAjaxCall();
}, 5000);
```

Comment: yes right now the timer is working but it still go to the controller just 1 time and then it's gone